# Kotlin: La interfaz no tiene constructor

Tags: kotlin, interface

Hice un proyecto en mi trabajo y me han pedido que lo pase a kotlin, despues de pasar todo el proyecto hay una parte que me da error de codigo todo el rato (no al ejecutarlo), y me pone que la interfaz no tiene parámetros. Claramente es mi primera vez en kotlin y no tengo ni idea pero me hago una idea. He intentado solucionarlo y no lo he consegui

Exactamente me da error al principio  en el `SpeechService.Lintener {`:

Codigo:

```
   //METODO
private val mSpeechServiceListener = SpeechService.Listener { text: String?, isFinal: Boolean ->
    if (isFinal) {
        mVoiceRecorder!!.dismiss()
    }

    if (mText != null && !TextUtils.isEmpty(text)) {
        runOnUiThread {
            if (isFinal) {

                if (mText!!.text.toString().equals("hola", ignoreCase = true) || b == true) {
                    if (b == true) {
                        mText!!.text = null
                        mTextMod!!.text = text

                        repro().onPostExecute(text)
                        random = 2
                    } else {
                        b = true
                        mText!!.text = null
                        val saludo = "Bienvenido, ¿que desea?"
                        mTextMod!!.text = saludo
                        repro().onPostExecute(saludo)
                    }
                }

            } else {
                mText!!.text = text
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Y aqui pongo a quien llama(que está en otra clase diferente)

```
interface Listener {

    fun onSpeechRecognized(text: String?, isFinal: Boolean)

}
```

Si me pudierais ayudar os lo agradeceria bastante

Comment: Y qué error es?

Comment: @DavidDPG me dice que la interfaz no tiene constructor

Answer (score 0):

Lo que pasa es que estas declarando una variable que retorna un callback pero al final no retornas nada.

Lo que deberias hacer es lo siguiente, en la clase donde tenes que implementar esa interfaz, implementala de la siguiente forma

```
class tuActivity: onSpeechRecognized{


override fun onSpeechRecognized(text: String?, isFinal: Boolean){
// aca haces la logica que necesitas y se la asignas a la variable mSpeechServiceListener anteriormente inicializada
}
```

Luego vas a llamar al metodo y le vas a pasar los parametros que necesita para poblar la variable que necesitas

```
onSpeechRecognized("texto de prueba",false)
```

Answer (score 0):

Solo puedes enviar una interfaz anomina cuando haces iterop de kolin a java. A esto se le llama [SAM Conversions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#sam-conversions). No es posible realizarlo con tipos declarados en kotlin.

Tienes que especificar el tipo del parametro y la implementacion del cuerpo de la interfaz si la interfaz esta definida en kolin:

```
SpeechService.Listener(object: Listener{
     override fun onSpeechRecognized(text: String?, isFinal: Boolean){
            //...
    }
})
```